# Single or double quotes use cases

Tags: ruby

I tend to mix single and double quotes in Ruby. I didn't find any manual about what which of them should I use. Of course, I have to use double quotes when **there is string interpolation**. But what about  the **normal cases**, what's the idiomatic, recommended style?

For example

```
gem "rack"
```

or

```
gem 'rack'
```

Please don't tell me: use whatever you want, I know I can, but that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: if u are going to use string interpolation, use double quotes. else use single quotes. there is no performance difference. "This isn't right" v/s 'This isn\'t right'

Comment: But... "whatever you want" as long as you are consistent shows up as the recommendation in [this style guide](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml) and [this one too](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide), which are the two top hits on google for Ruby style guide, but since you don't want to be told that, I won't give a recommendation.  All I will say is that there is no main consensus but double seems to me "more popular".  But seriously go ahead and use whichev^H^H^H (sorry could not resist) :)

Comment: When there is a choice, I prefer single quotes because I think it makes the code easier to read and is more aesthetically pleasing, but if you prefer the look of double quotes, by all means use single quotes anyway.

Comment: You've already said you know you can use whatever you want. That makes this just an opinion question, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most IDEs (For eg - RubyMine) recommend you to use single quote when you don't use string interpolation. But double quotes are required when you have special characters such as "\n", "\t" etc., in your string. Otherwise they will be treated as regular characters.

[image: double quote]

[**The Ruby Style Guide**](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) says you can use both, but have it consistent across your project/application.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently single quotes are dealt with in a slightly faster manner since the parser knows it won't have to look for anything nested within single quotes.

String interpolation should be considered, yes, but there are also cases when building strings that you need to use double quotes so that you can input newlines and single quotes as part of the string.  But this raises the argument as to whether you should be building strings with the %Q function so that you can enter newlines, etc.

Comment: I don't think single quotes are that faster that it maters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be consistent between when you write and read, then you have to use double quotes because the inspection of a string is in double quotes.